# How do I include the upper boundary of the bins in Matplotlib hist

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bins

When creating a histogram using `hist()` from `matplotlib`, the data falls into bins as such:

`lb ≤ x < ub`. How do I force it to behave like this: `lb < x ≤ ub`?

Additionally, the frequency table is shifted one bin lower compared to Excel, which produces an inaccurate measurement for my purpose.

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.array([23.5, 28, 29, 29, 29.5, 29.5, 30, 30, 30])
bins = np.array([20, 25, 30])
# Excel               1, 8
# Python          1,  5
```

Using the table as a reference, how do I force `hist()` to put values between 25 and 30 in bin 30 and not bin 25?

```
# in Python: 20 <-> 20 ≤ x < 25
# in Excel:  25 <-> 20 < x ≤ 25
```

Comment: What are you using to calculate? I've just checked on my machine, and calling `plt.hist(a, bins=[20, 25, 30])` produces two bins with [1, 8] counts.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: `how do I force hist() to...` Look through the Matplotlib source; make a copy of this function and put it in your project; modify it to do what you want.? Or writ your own hist function.

Comment: Maybe you can make use of one or more of its parameters to fudge the results - https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html

Comment: @Physmatik. Apologies, I extracted the results. My bins are actually range(0,200,5). If you include a 35 bin, you get [1, 5, 3]. I can post the entire range of data and results but this is my core issue and didn't want to be superfluous.

Comment: @wwii I'll attempt this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `numpy.digitize` might be interesting for you (from the documentation):

```
Return the indices of the bins to which each value in input array belongs.

`right`    order of bins  returned index `i` satisfies
=========  =============  ============================
``False``  increasing     ``bins[i-1] <= x < bins[i]``
``True``   increasing     ``bins[i-1] < x <= bins[i]``
``False``  decreasing     ``bins[i-1] > x >= bins[i]``
``True``   decreasing     ``bins[i-1] >= x > bins[i]``
```

Hopefully this clears also a common misunderstanding when working with bins.
The `bins` correspond to the vertices of a grid and a data point falls between **two** vertices / in **one** bin. Therefore a data point does not correspond to one single point in the `bins` array but to two.
Another thing one can see from this notation, is with `bins=[20, 25, 30]` bin 1 goes from 20-25 and bin 2 from 25-30, maybe the notation in excel is different?

Using the keyword `right` for a custom histogram function results in following code and plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([15,
                 17, 18, 20, 20, 20,
                 23.5, 24, 25, 25,
                 28, 29, 30, 30, 30])
bins = np.array([15, 20, 25, 30])


def custom_hist(x, bins, right=False):
    x_dig = np.digitize(x, bins=bins, right=right)
    u, c = np.unique(x_dig, return_counts=True)
    h = np.zeros(len(bins), dtype=int)
    h[u] = c
    return h


plt.hist(data, bins=bins,  color='b', alpha=0.7, label='plt.hist')
# array([3., 5., 7.]

height = custom_hist(x=data, bins=bins, right=True)
width = np.diff(bins)
width = np.concatenate((width, width[-1:]))
plt.bar(bins-width, height=height, width=width,
        align='edge', color='r', alpha=0.7, label='np.digitize')
plt.legend()
# This function also allows different sized bins
```

[image: custom hist]

Note that in the case of `right=True` `15` belongs to the bin ?<x<=15
which gives you a fourth bar in the histogram even so it is not explicitly included in the `bins`. If this is not wanted you have to treat the edge cases separately and maybe add the values to the first valid bin.
I guess that this is also the reason why we see an unexpected
behaviour with your example data. Matplotlib applies `lb ≤ x < ub` for the bins but nevertheless the 30ths get associated with the bin 25-30.
If we add an additional bin 30-35 we can see that now the 30ths are put in this bin. I guess that they apply the rule `lb ≤ x < ub` everywhere except at the edges, here the use `lb ≤ x ≤ ub`, which is also reasonable, but one has to be aware of it.

```py
data = np.array([23.5, 28, 29, 29, 29.5, 29.5, 30, 30, 30])
plt.hist(data, bins=np.array([20, 25, 30]),  color='b', alpha=0.7, label='[20, 25, 30]')
plt.hist(data, bins=np.array([20, 25, 30, 35]),  color='r', alpha=0.7, label='[20, 25, 30, 35]')
plt.legend()
```

[image: different bins]

Comment: Thank you scieronomic. The custom_hist() employing np.digitize worked perfectly. It aligns with Excel now. I obtained a much more accurate result for the mean in the first cluster of the histogram.